# bash to rename specific file type in directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to use `bash` to rename a specific `file type` which is `.bam.bai` and having trouble removing the text after the second underscore `_` in the filename. Currently I am only getting one file returned renamed after the first `_`, the other two files are deleted I would assume because they are duplicated.  Thank you and have a great holiday:).

**files in /home/cmccabe/example/folder**

```
IonXpress_007_MEVxz_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai
IonXpress_008_MEVxx_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai
IonXpress_009_MEVxy_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai
```

**desired output**

```
IonXpress_007.bam.bai
IonXpress_008.bam.bai
IonXpress_009.bam.bai
```

**Bash**

```
for file in /home/cmccabe/example/folder/*.bam.bai; do
mv -- "$file" "${file%%_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*}.bam.bai
done
```

**Current output**

```
IonXpress
```

Comment: Apart from a missing double quote character in the `mv` command, have you tried a common sense option such as including in the loop a debugging line like `echo mv -- "$file" "${file%%_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*}.bam.bai"` ?

Comment: Your code removes the `_009_` substring from the new name. `${file%%_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*}` expands for `IonXpress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `rename` utility then you can use:

```
rename -n 's/^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.+$/$1.bam.bai/' *.bam.bai

'IonXpress_007_MEVxz_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai' would be renamed to 'IonXpress_007.bam.bai'
'IonXpress_008_MEVxx_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai' would be renamed to 'IonXpress_008.bam.bai'
'IonXpress_009_MEVxy_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai' would be renamed to 'IonXpress_009.bam.bai'
```

If you don't have `rename` then you can use loop through these files and use `cut`:

```
for f in *.bam.bai; do echo mv "$f" "$(cut -d_ -f1-2 <<< "$f").bam.bai"; done

mv IonXpress_007_MEVxz_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai IonXpress_007.bam.bai
mv IonXpress_008_MEVxx_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai IonXpress_008.bam.bai
mv IonXpress_009_MEVxy_R_2016_11_18_10_45_10_user_S5-00580-14-Medexome.bam.bai IonXpress_009.bam.bai
```

Remove `echo` before `mv` once you're satisfied with the output.

Comment: Using the `rename` utility works, but it only renames the file in `stdout` not in the directory.  Thank you :).

Comment: It is because I used `rename -n` for dry run. Just use `rename  's/^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.+$/$1.bam.bai/' *.bam.bai` to rename them all.

Comment: Thank you, not familiar with `rename` but thank you for introducing me and for the help :).

Answer (score 1):

`${file%%_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*}` removes any character until the leftmost underscore character, including the three-digit number and its surrounding underscores. Thus, that expands to `IonXpress`.

Instead, my code removes any character from right to left until the second underscore followed by `MEV` substring:

```
for file in /home/cmccabe/example/folder/*.bam.bai
do
      mv -- "$file" "${file%%_MEV*}".bam.bai
done
```

Another option would be to select the 13 leftmost characters from the filename:

```
  mv -- "$file" "${file::13}".bam.bai
```

Answer (score 1):

A robust way to do it will be:

```
#!/bin/bash
mydir=/home/cmccabe/example/folder
regex="^([^_]+_[^_]+)"                 # Match a sequence of several not "_"
                                       # followed by a "_" and by
                                       # a second sequence of not "_".

cd "$mydir"                            # work only on files inside mydir.
shopt -s nullglob                      # Make the pattern null if no file.

for file in ./[^.].bam.bai; do         # To avoid matching a renamed file.
    [[ $file =~ $regex ]];             # test if the file match the regex.
    f="./${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.bam.bai"
    echo \
    mv "./$file" "$f"                  # execute the rename.
done
```